# Setup https proxy for pip install command within tox environment

Tags: python, https, proxy, pip, tox

I need to setup **https proxy** for the **pip** install command within **tox** environment.

Currenly, I have something like this:

```
...
[toxenv:test]
install_command = pip install {opts} {packages}
commands = 
    <command1>
    <command2>
...
```

If I use just pip command, like:

```
pip install <package>
```

I will get into error, because I am behind the proxy.

So I do something like this and it work like a sharm:

```
https_proxy=<proxy_url> pip install <package>
```

But, the problem is that I need proxy to be setup **only** for pip install command, and for other commands (*command1*, *command2*, ...) **https_proxy** should be unset.

So the question is how to setup https_proxy for pip install command **only** in tox and make it **not set** for all other commands.

P.s. Doing something like this doesn't work:

```
install_command = https_proxy=<proxy_url> pip install {opts} {packages}
```

P.s.s. The ***pip --proxy*** option doesn't help too, since it sets the ***http_proxy*** only.

Beforehand thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set env variable in tox sessions,  and wraps your pip command in a script

`proxy_pip.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
https_proxy=$my_https_proxy http_proxy=$http_proxy pip $@
```

`tos.ini`

```
[testenv]
setenv =    
   my_http_proxy = <proxy_url>
   my_https_proxy = <proxy_url>
install_command = proxy_pip.sh install {opts} {packages}
commands = 
    <command1>
    <command2>
```